# How to get facebook user name In URL by using facebook id?

Tags: c#, facebook, url, converters, userid

when I enter url with an user id(1111111111) https://www.facebook.com/1111111111 the browser redirected to  https://www.facebook.com/kamal.a.ewee. kamal.a.ewee is the user name appear in the url represented by the user id. If I have user id how to convert it in the user name like
kamal.a.ewee ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
identifier = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"))
graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + identifier
urlJsonData = getGraphData(graphUrl)
```

Should work the same (that is result with the same data) for both:

```
url = http://www.facebook.com/southpark
```

And

```
url = http://www.facebook.com/6708787004
```

(you'll obviously need to implement the getGraphData method).

Also, the 2nd url form in the question is not a valid url for pages, at least not from my tests, I get:

You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.